# Remove histogram classification labels

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, histogram

Is there a way to remove this numbers associated with vertical segments in histograms in QGIS?

I am using 2.18.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are referring to a Histogram viewgraph which is available when we choose a `Graduated` style in the  `Layer Properties | Style`.

If you do not have to stick with this function, alternative one is in the `Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Graphics | Vector layer histogram`.

Could be too simple, but from your question this seems to fit for your purpose.